# UML Class Diagram HashMap with different Key datatype using Qualified Association

Tags: uml, class-diagram

By using the qualified association element of UML Class Diagram, we can create HashMap as the datatype of one of our class attributes (see [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398623&seqNum=16)). In my case, I have to use HashMap with different key datatype (String and int) if the audience would be only with Java developers I would provide UML Class diagram as below:

[image]

and I guess this is just fine. However, my audience is unknown so I'm trying to provide a UML Class Diagram as general as I can. For example, the HashMap can be Dictionary in another programming language.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The Qualified Association, which you cited, is the implementation-independent way to represent it. See the other examples at https://www.uml-diagrams.org/property.html#qualifier

Comment: @Fuhrmanator qualified associations are implementation independent, but I think the type `HashMap<...,...>` is not.

Comment: Wouldn't this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8870950/3723423  ?

Comment: @Christophe I was thinking one does not specify attributes of a class when there is a qualified association. It's hard to reason about Strings and Class as types.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator see here the part that explains that you can use an association end as an attribute (and making the bridge btw class and type): https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html